# Bad input updating attributes with APS Data Management API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management, autodesk-construction-cloud

I am trying to update an attribute of an item as it is explained in the doccumentation but I get the BAD_INPUT response.

https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-PATCH/

I verified that the id´s of the projects and items that are put as parameters are correct but I don´t understand what Id should I put in the body section. I used the same Id of the parameter for the body.

[BAD INPUT response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gUnT.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)

Comment: ok, the image is not relevant, I am doing the same as in the documentation but without getting the same result.

Comment: Seems to be the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69544923/autodesk-forge-api-patch-item-input-error

Comment: Yes, it is the same question, but the response doesn`t serve me as I can´t do it this way. I need to do it with the same version. Is there any other way to solve it?